# Format Muilty dimentional array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I get json data as showing below.

```
[  

{
      "id":5,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      "change_log_id":2,
      "field_name":"full_name",
      "current_value":"cur14111r name",
      "previous_value":"old11111 name"
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      "change_log_id":2,
      "field_name":"country",
      "current_value":"Syriya11111",
      "previous_value":"America1111"
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      "change_log_id":2,
      "field_name":"school",
      "current_value":"HMV11111",
      "previous_value":"TMV11111"
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      "change_log_id":2,
      "field_name":"nick_name",
      "current_value":"Cokka1111",
      "previous_value":"Kukka1111"
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-05T23:38:08.000Z",
      "change_log_id":1,
      "field_name":"full_name",
      "current_value":"curr name",
      "previous_value":"old name"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-05T23:38:08.000Z",
      "change_log_id":1,
      "field_name":"country",
      "current_value":"Syriya",
      "previous_value":"America"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-05T23:38:08.000Z",
      "change_log_id":1,
      "field_name":"school",
      "current_value":"HMV",
      "previous_value":"TMV"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "entity_id":122,
      "entity_type":"STUDENT",
      "edit_type":"UPDATE",
      "created_by":122,
      "created_date":"2017-04-05T23:38:08.000Z",
      "change_log_id":1,
      "field_name":"nick_name",
      "current_value":"Cokka",
      "previous_value":"Kukka"
   }
]
```

I need to format this Json using `JavaScript. arr[change_log_id][id]["column_name"] = column vale;`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: where do you get `column_name` from?

Comment: What you are expecting ?

Comment: It would probably make more sense if you posted the array structure you're trying to create, along with your attempt at achieveing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use `Array.prototype.reduce()` as follows.

```
var input = [ ... ];

var output = input.reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc[value.change_log_id] = acc[value.change_log_id] || {};
    acc[value.change_log_id][value.id] = acc[value.change_log_id][value.id] || {};
    acc[value.change_log_id][value.id][value.current_value] = value.current_value;

    return acc;
}, []);
```

On your data set it produces the following result:

```
[ ,
  { '1': { 'curr name': 'curr name' },
    '2': { HMV: 'HMV' },
    '3': { Syriya: 'Syriya' },
    '4': { Cokka: 'Cokka' } },
  { '5': { 'cur14111r name': 'cur14111r name' },
    '6': { HMV11111: 'HMV11111' },
    '7': { Syriya11111: 'Syriya11111' },
    '8': { Cokka1111: 'Cokka1111' } } ]
```